# When building a project using react native as an apk in Android Studio, the following error occurs

Tags: react-native, android-studio, apk

> Task :packages:react-native-codegen:android:buildCodegenCLI

> react-native-codegen@0.0.7 prepublish /tmp/tmp.Yy5pPOnaYt
> yarn run build

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN prepublish-on-install As of npm@5, `prepublish` scripts are deprecated.
npm WARN prepublish-on-install Use `prepare` for build steps and `prepublishOnly` for upload-only.
npm WARN prepublish-on-install See the deprecation note in `npm help scripts` for more information.
sh: line 1: yarn: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! react-native-codegen@0.0.7 prepublish: `yarn run build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-native-codegen@0.0.7 prepublish script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/csk882/.npm/_logs/2023-01-20T02_59_21_039Z-debug.log

> Task :packages:react-native-codegen:android:buildCodegenCLI FAILED
Execution failed for task ':packages:react-native-codegen:android:buildCodegenCLI'.
> Process 'command '/home/csk882/mt/metamask-mobile/node_modules/react-native/packages/react-native-codegen/android/../scripts/oss/build.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

An error occurs when executing apk build in android studio

After building normally, the app should be deployed, but a build error occurred and it does not proceed any further.

Comment: What do you don't understand on the error message `yarn: command not found`? Your system is missing a command so please install it and try again.

Comment: It builds well with the ./gradlew assembleRelease command in the android location of the react project folder.
My problem is directly above when generating apk in Android Studio.

Comment: Which version of AndroidStudio do you use?

Comment: Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023
Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.15.0-58-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    idea.plugin.protoeditor (221.6095)

Current Desktop: Undefined